# Error Code: 1416. Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run .sql file/import into MySQL database, however, I am running into `Error Code: 1416. Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field` .

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE `listings` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  .  
  .  
  .  
  .  
  `location` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=78 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

```
INSERT INTO `listings` VALUES (
   1,
   .
   .
   .
   'GBP',
   '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\ÐoN\Ûu%º¿0žACÁI@',
   51.61100420,-0.10213410,
   '[]',
   'London',
   NULL,
   'UK'
```

I am using MySQL Workbench v8.0.15

Comment: in  all your unreadable example is not clear what you are trying to insert, how may fields do you have any way. Show also the create table of listings. because in all the text i cn't see any geometyr data at all, but maybe it is hidden somewhere

Comment: Ok i counted 52 columns, that is a lot , but still for number 1 i could find any geometry data a longitude latitude .

Comment: I added the create table statement and made the code more readable now.

Comment: @nbk The error seems to be appear from `location` point DEFAULT NULL and the encoding for point datatype seems to be off.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that what MySQL expects is a kind of binary format and not a string even it is a representation, but I converted it into binary and it still will not insert the data.

When you really want to save it you must use:

```
POINT(51.61100420,-0.10213410)
```

instead of your string.

I think your backup program does something wrong.
When exporting using MySQL Workbench, Points look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tespoint` VALUES (_binary '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ý[¸b5\ÎI@\ÐoN\Ûu%º¿',51.61100420,-0.10213410);
```

Comment: right, point data is set of coords that are being inserted into the table. however, the values that are being passed have strange encoding type -- '\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\ÐoN\Ûu%º¿ 0žACÁI@'

Comment: For context, I am running a .sql file created from mysql daily dump.

Comment: What chaeacter set are you running, where the dump comes from? Is it different from that where you insert the data?

Comment: The dump is auto-generated from a service I use. Schema is of character set: utf8mb4. Create and INSERT tables also use utf8 character set, which is default encoding for mySQL, I think.

Comment: Workbench and phpmyadnin can export and import point data. You should give it a try

Comment: I am using mySQL Workbench v8.0.15 to run the script. Haven't tried, phpmyadmin, I'll check it out.

Comment: I have added what mysql workbench exports for your data. So i think you should check the program that makes your backup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106730/discussion-between-kms-and-nbk).